# jQuery: How to execute code before event happens and have results as param at event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have set of elements, which I can add dynamically:

```
<div id="some-id-1" data-id="1" class="some">
<canvas />
</div>
<div id="some-id-2" data-id="2" class="some">
<canvas />
</div>
<div id="some-id-3" data-id="3" class="some">
<canvas />
</div>
...
```

I want to attach events to specific set item. To implement it I have such code:

```
$('body')
    .on('click', 'canvas', function (event) {
        var idx = $(this).parents('.some').data('id');
        wrap[idx].action1(event);
    })
    .on('mousemove mouseout', 'canvas', function () {
        var idx = $(this).parents('.some').data('id');
        wrap[idx].action2();
    })
    .on('mousemove', 'canvas', function (event) {
        var idx = $(this).parents('.some').data('id');
        wrap[idx].action3(event);
    });
```

At every event I need this extra line to get element id, which I clicked, which is index at array of objects. I want to get rid off this line.

Is there any way to call `var idx = $(this).parents('.some').data('id');` before events and pass `idx` as param to event?

Or any other way to organize code and not to write `var idx = $(this).parents('.some').data('id');` everywhere.

Comment: So what is the problem are you not getting `idx` value? BTW where is your `canvas` start tag in HTML?

Comment: impossible, how will the code "know" which canvas element is "about to" trigger an event?

Comment: @DeepakBiswal problem in duplication. it's dummy template, there is no problem with `canvas`

Comment: @JaromandaX made a little update. Maybe any better option to organize code in such case, to avoid duplicates?

Comment: can you show the wrap[].action1 action2 action3 code? Would be better to have one action function with a parameter idx; newAction(idx)

Comment: @viakondratiuk - code could be cleaner if you add `data-id="n"` to the canvases rather than (or as well as, doesn't matter) to the containing div

Comment: @TobiasBeuving My code is different from this one, which I provided. I made it for simplification. Maybe you are right and I need to change design a little.

Comment: @JaromandaX I understand your point, but I need `data-id="n"` at top level, I also have controls and other staff which depend on it.

Comment: that's why I said "or as well as" - added an answer - see how that looks for you

Comment: About the canvasses: do you have code 'in' them?

Comment: Are all the canvasses the same?

Comment: @TobiasBeuving no, there could be different setting for them, for width and heights

Answer (score 0):

Try [jquery custom events](https://learn.jquery.com/events/introduction-to-custom-events/):

```
$( document ).on( "myCustomEvent", {
    foo: "bar"
}, function( event, idx ) {
    console.log( event.data.foo ); // "bar"
    console.log( idx);           // idx

});



var idx = $(this).parents('.some').data('id');

$( document ).trigger( "myCustomEvent", [ idx ] );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try something below. It will handle each canvas click.

```
$('body')
    .on('click', 'canvas', function (event) {
        var idx = $(this).parents('.some').data('id');
        console.log(idx);
        wrap[idx].action1(event);

    });
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood a little. I can handle `canvas` clicks. I have several events attached to them. And I want to track each event for each canvas. That is why at very beginning of each event I need to find object idx. And this produces a lot of duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

"copy" the `data-id` to the canvas

```
$('.some canvas').each(function() {
    $(this).data('id', $(this).parents('.some').data('id'));
});
```

then the code can look like this

```
$('body')
    .on('click', 'canvas', function (event) {
        wrap[$(this).data('id')].action1(event);
    })
    .on('mousemove mouseout', 'canvas', function () {
        wrap[$(this).data('id')].action2();
    })
    .on('mousemove', 'canvas', function (event) {
        wrap[$(this).data('id')].action3(event);
    });
```